# UPDATE table SET column = GREATEST(column+number,0)

Tags: mysql, sql-update, unsigned

I have a table. One column is `INT UNSIGNED`, so cannot be less than zero. I want to subtract a number but in case the number is greater that the value already, I want to SET it equal to zero.

How can I achieve this?

```
UPDATE table SET **column = greatest(column-number,0)** WHERE customer_id=?
```

doesn't did the trick, but works when `number<0` (adds a value).

Comment: Can you share specific scenario in figure (in inputs and outputs).

Comment: *doesn't did the trick* -- what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like:

```
 UPDATE table SET column = IF(column>number,column-number,0) WHERE customer_id=?;
```